# Meteor check available versions available for atmosphere js package

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

Is it possible to check all available versions of an atmospherejs package?
For example, I am trying to install the `twbs:bootstrap@=4.0.0-alpha.4` following their [github page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/)

But this does not install giving error:

> no such version twbs:bootstrap@=4.0.0-alpha.4

Hence I am looking to find a way to check which versions are available for any given atmospherejs meteor package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
meteor show twbs:bootstrap
```

or

```
meteor show --show-all twbs:bootstrap
```

for older or pre-released versions. Latest available version is `4.0.0-alpha2`